# CombineByKey object is not iterable

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to learn CombineByKey with Pyspark. Basically just recreating groupByKey using CombineByKey.

My Rdd has objects like so, stored in pairRdds. Each pair is an object stored in a class (MyClass) variable myObj.

myObj example: `obj1 = ((a, b),(A,0,0))`

Where the key is `(a,b)` and the value is `(A,0,0)`

Say my example RDD looks like:

```
Rdd = [((a, b),(A,3,0)), ((a, b),(B,2,7)), ((a, c),(C,5,2)), ((a, d),(D,8,6))]
```

My final output I would like to look like:

```
Output = [((a, b),[(A,3,0), (B,2,7)]),((a, c),(C,5,2)), ((a, d),(D,8,6))]
```

Following some of the examples: [`combineByKey`, pyspark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50070775/combinebykey-pyspark?noredirect=1&lq=1) 
and 
[Apache Spark: What is the equivalent implementation of RDD.groupByKey() using RDD.aggregateByKey()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31081563/apache-spark-what-is-the-equivalent-implementation-of-rdd-groupbykey-using-rd)

```
comb = cell_location_flat.combineByKey(
        lambda row: [row],
        lambda rows, row: rows + [row],
        lambda rows1, rows2: rows1 + rows2,
    )

print(comb.collect())
```

I get the following error.

```
Caused by: org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 372, in main
    process()
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 367, in process
    serializer.dump_stream(func(split_index, iterator), outfile)
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/rdd.py", line 2499, in pipeline_func
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/rdd.py", line 2499, in pipeline_func
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/rdd.py", line 352, in func
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/rdd.py", line 1861, in combineLocally
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/shuffle.py", line 238, in mergeValues
    for k, v in iterator:
TypeError: 'MyClass' object is not iterable
```

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?
Thanks for any replies!

Comment: Never would have thought it was an issue with the class. Thanks for pointing me to that link. Worked perfectly.